# Skype4Com Auto reject calls vb.net

Tags: vb.net, skype, skype4com

Hey i was wondering if anyone knows how to auto reject calls on skype with skype4com on vb.net if anyone could help me would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If you are still wondering, it's done like this:

When registering your oSkype, make it "WithEvents":

```
Public WithEvents oSkype As New SKYPE4COMLib.Skype
```

Then, once it has events, you need to handle the CallStatus event:

```
Private Sub oSkype_CallStatus(pCall As SKYPE4COMLib.Call, Status As SKYPE4COMLib.TCallStatus) Handles oSkype.CallStatus

End Sub
```

Then, in this handler, you need to check if the Status is Ringing:

```
If Status = SKYPE4COMLib.TCallStatus.clsRinging Then

End If
```

Then, finally, you need to end the call if it is:

```
pCall.Finish()
```

So, in all, your code should be:

```
Public Class Form1
Public WithEvents oSkype As New SKYPE4COMLib.Skype
Private Sub oSkype_CallStatus(pCall As SKYPE4COMLib.Call, Status As SKYPE4COMLib.TCallStatus) Handles oSkype.CallStatus
    If Status = SKYPE4COMLib.TCallStatus.clsRinging Then
        pCall.Finish()
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

From this you can modify this to deny calls from a certain user, allow certain users etc. But you can figure that out yourself.